# Ionic command not working only in Git Bash

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, git-bash

Whenever I try to use `ionic` command in Git Bash, I get a "*command not found*" error. But when I test this command in Powershell or CMD, it works. It's only in Git Bash where it doesn't work.

This worked fine earlier, but then stopped working after downgrading my node to **v13.13.0** and npm to **v6.12.1**.

This is the complete error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

And what I also realized about this file path is that it used both "\" and "/" symbols instead of sticking to only 1. I made sure to check my environment variable path if it's set correctly, and also restarted my Git Bash but the error still persists.